# How can I use Python to download all the pages from a search query?

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

For example, for this url: https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/type=decision&jId=on&all=Duties%20liabilities%20officers%20directors

How can I use Python to download all the 3416 cases and 315 legislation as html files to my local disk?

Answer (score 0):

Try this site for probably the best Python downloading/scraping library around.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Well-documented, widely-used, robust, pretty quick, etc.